# Rust dependency error in online hardware simulation tool WOKWI ESP32

Tags: rust, mqtt, hardware, esp32

I am trying to implement very simple "Smart home" system in Rust. Signal is going to humidity sensor and lights a light bulb. I don't have real ESP32 at home, so to simulate ESP32 I am using the [WOKWI](https://wokwi.com/) emulator. I ran into a problem because of old version of one of dependencies and can't solve it. I tried different methods, changing versions, different libraries, but it didn't work, so I need your help.

*main.rs*

```
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

// Import necessary crates and modules
use std::arch::asm;
// use core::arch::asm - NOT WORKING!!
use core::fmt::Write;
use esp32_hal::prelude::*;
use esp32_hal::dht::{Dht, DhtBuilder};
use esp32_hal::wifi::{EspWifi, WifiConfig};
use esp32_hal::mqtt::{MqttClient, MqttConfig};
use esp32_hal::gpio::Gpio;
use esp32_hal::clock::Clocks;
use panic_halt as _;
use xtensa_lx_rt::entry;
use esp32_hal::dht::DhtType;
use esp32_hal::pac::Peripherals;
use esp32_hal::pac::CorePeripherals;
use esp32_hal::delay::delay_ms;

// Wi-Fi configuration
const SSID: &str = "dd-wrt";
const PASSWORD: &str = "0000000000";

// MQTT server address
const MQTT_SERVER: &str = "192.168.1.103";

// DHT sensor configuration
const DHT_PIN: u8 = 13;
const DHT_TYPE: DhtType = DhtType::Dht22;

// LED GPIO pin
const LED: u8 = 12;

// MQTT topics
const TEMP_TOPIC: &str = "smarthome/room1/temp";
const LED_TOPIC: &str = "smarthome/room1/led"; // 1=on, 0=off

#[entry]
fn main() -> ! {
    // Initialize peripherals and core peripherals
    let dp = Peripherals::take().unwrap();
    let cp = CorePeripherals::take().unwrap();

    // Initialize system clocks
    let clocks = Clocks::new(cp.SYST);

    // Configure GPIO pins
    let pins = dp.GPIO.split();
    let _led = pins.gpio12.into_push_pull_output();

    // Initialize DHT sensor
    let dht = DhtBuilder::new(DHT_PIN, DHT_TYPE).init().unwrap();

    // Initialize and configure Wi-Fi
    let wifi = EspWifi::new(dp.RTC_CNTL, dp.SPI_WIFI, dp.WIFI);
    let wifi_config = WifiConfig::new(SSID, PASSWORD);
    wifi.set_config(wifi_config);
    wifi.connect();

    // Initialize and configure MQTT client
    let mqtt_config = MqttConfig::new(MQTT_SERVER);
    let mut mqtt_client = MqttClient::new(dp.MQTT, mqtt_config);

    // Main loop
    loop {
        // Read temperature from DHT sensor
        if let Ok(temperature) = dht.read_temperature() {
            // Format temperature value as a string
            let mut msg = [0u8; 20];
            write!(&mut msg[..], "{:.2}", temperature).unwrap();

            // Publish temperature to MQTT topic
            mqtt_client.publish(TEMP_TOPIC, &msg, 0, false).unwrap();
        }

        // Delay for 1 minute (60000 milliseconds)
        delay_ms(60000);
    }
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "rust_project_esp32"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Sergio Gasquez <sergio.gasquez@gmail.com>"]
edition = "2021"
license = "MIT OR Apache-2.0"

[dependencies]
esp32-hal = "0.3.0"
#xtensa-lx-rt = "0.3.0"
esp-backtrace = { version = "0.7.0", features = [
    "esp32",
    "panic-handler",
    "print-uart",
] }
esp-println = { version = "0.5.0", features = ["esp32"] }
xtensa-lx-rt = { version = "0.15.0", features = ["esp32"], optional = true }

[dependencies.panic-halt]
version = "0.2.0"



[features]
default = ["rt"]
rt = ["xtensa-lx-rt"]
```

**Error:**

```
Compiling xtensa-lx v0.4.0
error: cannot find macro `asm` in this scope
  --> /home/esp/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/xtensa-lx-0.4.0/src/interrupt.rs:99:14
   |
99 |     unsafe { asm!("rsr.intenable {0}", out(reg) mask) };
   |              ^^^
   |
   = help: consider importing this macro:
           core::arch::asm

error: cannot find macro `asm` in this scope
 --> /home/esp/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/xtensa-lx-0.4.0/src/timer.rs:7:14
  |
7 |     unsafe { asm!("rsr.ccompare0 {0}", out(reg) x, options(nostack)) };
  |              ^^^
  |
  = help: consider importing this macro:
          core::arch::asm

error: cannot find macro `asm` in this scope
  --> /home/esp/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/xtensa-lx-0.4.0/src/timer.rs:14:14
   |
14 |     unsafe { asm!("rsr.ccompare1 {0}", out(reg) x, options(nostack)) };
   |              ^^^
   |
   = help: consider importing this macro:
           core::arch::asm

error: cannot find macro `asm` in this scope
  --> /home/esp/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/xtensa-lx-0.4.0/src/timer.rs:21:14
   |
21 |     unsafe { asm!("rsr.ccompare2 {0}", out(reg) x, options(nostack)) };
   |              ^^^
   |
   = help: consider importing this macro:
           core::arch::asm

error: cannot find macro `asm` in this scope
  --> /home/esp/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/xtensa-lx-0.4.0/src/timer.rs:37:9
   |
37 |         asm!("
   |         ^^^
   |
   = help: consider importing this macro:
           core::arch::asm
```

Comment: Did you do what the error message says to do?

Comment: Bros lmao. @romkey I added dependency with ```use core::arch::asm;``` from official repository.

Comment: @isaactfa interrupt.rs is component from xtensa-lx v.0.4.0 which is compiling as you can see

Comment: I do apologize, I misread the error message and jumped to conclusions without double checking myself. Can you share the exact cargo command you are using to build this?

Comment: @isaactfa WOKWI doesn't provide detailed/complete info how it build a project. All I can tell you, that it is using default ```cargo build``` command and takes dependencies from Cargo.toml. Cargo.toml you can check in my post. Thanks.

Comment: You're using an insanely outdated version of `esp32-hal` (0.3.0 instead of 0.12.0) that is incompatible with the other crates.

Comment: @isaactfa I know, I can't use newer version in ESP32 WOKWI Rust project

Answer (score 1):

I found this example from expressif that imports asm: https://github.com/espressif/rust-esp32-example/blob/main/components/rustlib/src/lib.rs

Comparing your solution with the one from the example it looks like you are missing the feature flags:

```
#![cfg_attr(not(version("1.59")), feature(asm))]
#![cfg_attr(
       all(version("1.58"), target_arch = "xtensa"),
       feature(asm_experimental_arch)
    )]

use core::arch::asm;
```

However unless you are on a older version of rust simply adding the feature flags without any switching.

```
#![feature(asm)]

use core::arch::asm;
```

I don't think you can use `std::arch::asm` unless you remove `no_std` or use extern crate to reimport std again.

Comment: Pretty good answer, but unfortunately none of these solutions are working